# Reduce line-height in R ggplot in geom_label() and geom_text(), when line-breaking with \n

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

The following code creates the following graph:

```
data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4), y = c(1,2,3,4)) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_label(aes(x = 2.5, y = 2.5, label = 'label here \n with break'), fill = '#dddddd')
```

[image]

We need to reduce the gap between the two rows of text. I believe this corresponds to the css properly `line-height`, which when reduced will bring lines closer together as the line height is smaller.

We cannot render 2 geom_labels with different `y` values, as the vertical positioning doesn't remain consistent with 2 geom_labels when resizing the graph. We need to use the 1 geom_label() with `\n` for line break and we need to reduce the gap between the two lines of text. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the `lineheight` argument in `geom_label`:

```
data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4), y = c(1,2,3,4)) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_label(aes(x = 2.5, y = 2.5, label = 'label here \n with break'), 
             fill = '#dddddd', lineheight = 0.5)
```

[image]